# Is it possible to deprecate function and replace it with a computed property with the same name in Swift?

Tags: swift4

I am trying to convert some of my functions to computed properties with the same names, but get the following error:

> Invalid redeclaration of 'name()'

(See code sample below for the simplified version of the code I tried)

Currently, I only have the function in my code, but would like to replace that with a property version.  I need to keep supporting the function for a while and would not like to change the name since that is what the consumers are used to. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Simplified Code Sample:

```
class Person {
private var _name: String?

public var name: String? {
    return _name
}

@available(*, deprecated, message: "Use name property")
public func name() -> String? {
    return name
}
```

}

I.o.w I would like to move from person.name() to person.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible, you'll have to come up with a different name for your new `name` property if you don't want to change `name()`.

The reason for this is that given

```
class Person {
  func name() -> String { return "Joe" }
}
```

this is valid code:

```
let p = Person()
let name = p.name()  // a String
let nameFun = p.name // a function returning a String
```

and introducing a differently typed `Person.name` creates a conflict.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer.  It makes complete sense.